# Initialize a std::vector of structures to zero

Tags: c++

I am guaranteed to initialize a vector of struct with each element initialized to zero with that code ?

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int a, b;
    float f;
};

int main()
{
    // 100 A's initialized to zero (a=0, b=0, f=0.0)
    // std::vector<A> my_vector(100, {}); does not compile
    std::vector<A> my_vector(100, A{});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the problem with the code you have? `A{}` is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) which for a class like yours should lead to [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) (where all members are set to "zero").

Comment: I edited the code for clarification

Comment: I saw a lot of question regarding vector of built-in but not vector of structs, it's just to be sure

Comment: `std::vector<A> my_vector(100, {{}});` will compile. But your code a couple lines above will throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is guaranteed since `A{}` is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> - As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of **aggregates** for which no initializers are provided.

You can also use:

```
std::vector<A> my_vector(100, {0,0,0});
```

Comment: `{0, 1, 1.f}` would not initialize each element to zero though ;-) (*"with each element initialized to zero"*).

Comment: @Jarod42 Obviously. I have just chosen `{0,1,1}` to get my point across. I was thinking of writing `{0,0,0}` but then chose not to since i thought OP will understand the point i am making. Changing it to `{0,0,0}` to initialize each element to zero is **trivial**. So i didn't bother to change it to `{0,0,0}`. Edited now.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : Yes

To know how refer below :
when you write

```
std::vector<A> my_vector(...)
```

you are doing [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) if the parentheses are empty, or [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) if non-empty.

and when you write A{} you are doing [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)  which implies value initialization if the braces are empty, or [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) if the initialized object is an aggregate.

as your parentheses are non-empty  so below code

```
std::vector<A> my_vector(100, A{});
```

is interpreted as

```
std::vector<A> my_vector(/*created vector of 100 elements */ 100, /* by list  Initialization of struct with default values*/A{});
```

As A{} is empty in this case you are doing value initialization which is leading to [zero_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)
as

> 2. As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are guaranteed to have zero initialization with that code

Comment: Please consider putting this type of short answer as a comment to the original question.

Comment: @biqarboy - Please do not suggest that. Answers belong in the answer section, there is no length requirement. If you think it's not useful, downvote as the tooltip says.